# Finding a value at which TD(lambda) and Monte Carlo Are Similar

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods, monte-carlo-methods

Let's say that I'm trying to find a value of lambda for which running a TD(lambda) method will produce the same results as a Monte Carlo method (within a small margin or error, of course).  One of the ways that I've thought about doing this would be to calculate the Monte Carlo value (which is equivalent to TD(1)), and then assign lambda a small value and run TD(lambda) in a loop until the return converges with the MC value, adjusting lambda in small amounts until reached.  This seems computationally heavy though (imagine hundreds of iterations of calculated TD(lambda) until we reach the convergence value of lambda.

Is there a less computationally heavy way of doing this?

Comment: Interesting subject...I found Self Learning Monte Carlo paper and it looks like a few computer code in GitHub like https://github.com/sylvialee12/SelfLearning-MonteCarlo,  https://github.com/misawann/self-learningMC Also one research paper at https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/162754.162763

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the formula for TD($\lambda$) and maybe Monte-Carlo so that there is no confusion.

Comment: I am confused, given that $\lambda=1$ is a solution to your question, what exactly are we looking for? Other $\lambda$s with the same property or something else?